# How to organize ellipses in multiple rows using for loop in Processing

Tags: arrays, for-loop, processing

I was trying to create a group of ellipses with varying radius in Processing. I created an array of radius values and used a for loop to create the series of ellipses with varying radius.

There are eight ellipses arranged in a linear manner. Instead of keeping the ellipses in a single row, I wanted them to be placed in two or three rows. How can I do that? What would be the nature of the for loop in such a situation?

```java
float [] r = {10,20,30,50,30,22,16,12};


void setup(){
size(400,400);
smooth();
}

void draw(){
background(225);

for(int i = 0;i<r.length;i++){

  ellipse(50+i*30,50,r[i],r[i]);

}

}
```

Comment: @gsamaras he did, he said the programming language was [Processing](https://processing.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting out a piece of paper and a pencil and drawing a few examples. What is the `x,y` position of each circle? What is the index of each circle? You probably won't understand any answer until you notice the pattern yourself.

Anyway, you could do this with a single for loop: use the [modulo operator](https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html) to calculate the position, and/or store the `y` position in a variable that you increment.

But it might be easier to just use a nested for loop:

```java
float [] r = {
  10, 20, 30, 50, 30, 22, 16, 12
};

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  background(225);

  for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++) {
      int index = row*4 + column;
      ellipse(50+column*30, 50+row*50, r[index], r[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @v.k. What are your edits changing? I don't see a difference in the side-by-side comparison, but I might be missing something!

Comment: @KevinWorkman Syntax highlight. `<!-- language: lang-java -->` . Much better to see the code ;) You can see it in  side-by-side-markdown view